# Installing scrapy on vmware OS X but getting various exceptions

Tags: python, scrapy, vmware

The exception is,

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyasn1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use :

```
sudo pip install <package>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
```

This means you don't have root permision.
if you are using ubuntu or mac you can either use

```
sudo pip install <package>
```

else in your terminal type

```
sudo gnome-terminal
```

this will give you root permission then you can use

```
pip install <package>
```

some times in windows same error occurs then you need run cmd as administrator this will resolve the problem

Keep coding keep learning

Kudos to Stackoverflow

Comment: Just to clarify, i am trying to run scrapy on a dedicated OS using VMware. When I'm using the code "sudo gnome-terminal" i get an error, "Command not found". Scrapy works with dedicated OS also as I checked the documentation, they even recommend using virtual machine but I'm not able to install scrapy.

Comment: do I have to change some class path or root permission ?

Comment: 'dsenableroot' for mac

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me was found on this link "https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scrapy/scrapy_environment.html"